# How can I take into account the zeros to the left of the number? Python

Tags: python-3.x

How can I take into account the zeros to the left of the number but still be an int and not a string?
I don't want to accept values like 1, 10, 100, 1000... It must be 8 digits like 00000001 or 00015028
(This is just a small piece of the program)

```
for i in range(size):
    CC = int(input("Civil ID: "))
    while CC < 000000001 or CC >99999999:
        print("Unvalid Civil ID, please insert 8 digits from your Civil ID: ")
        CC = int(input("Civil ID: "))
```

Comment: while ( ( ! isnumeric(CC)) or (CC < 1) or (CC > 99999999) or (len(CC) != 8)) { print ... }

Comment: as a answer to your question : your solution makes direct cast to int, the information about user input string length is lost during this cast. I just store the raw input in separate variable so some checks can be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about ?

```
for i in range(size):
    input_string = input("Civil ID: ")
    CC = int(input_string)
    while len(input_string) != 8 or CC < 000000001 or CC >99999999:
        print("Unvalid Civil ID, please insert 8 digits from your Civil ID: ")
        input_string = input("Civil ID: ")
        CC = int(input_string)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But I don't understand why you did it like that 

input_string = input("Civil ID: ") 
CC = int(input_string) 
while len(input_string) ...


instead of 

CC = int(input("Civil ID: "))
while len(CC) != 8 ...

I tried and I know that the second way gives me error, but I don't understand why